# Why the element I created by js has different style with that I directly added in html file

Tags: javascript, html, css

Jan and Feb are elements directly added to html. Mar to Dec are elements generated by js. I was wondering why the style of Jan and Feb are different with those created by javascript.

```js
var monthsElement = document.getElementsByClassName("months")[0]
var monthList = ["Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
for (var month in monthList) {
    var newMonth = document.createElement("span")
    monthsElement.appendChild(newMonth)
    newMonth.setAttribute("class","month-hover")
    newMonth.innerHTML = monthList[month]
   

}
```

```css
.month-hover:hover{
  
  color:#27e779 !important;
  
}

.months {
  color: #AAAAAA;
  position: relative;
  left: 350px;
  top: 90px;
  word-spacing: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="calendar-base">
        <div class="months">
            <span class="month-hover">Jan</span>
            <span class="month-hover">Feb</span>
            
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Seems pretty basic. Inline elements are sensitive to white space in your code and your Jan and Feb spans have spaces after them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`word-spacing` is a style for paragraphs `<p>`. For this case you will need to use either `padding` or appending all your text in one tag.

Hope this helps :)

```js
var monthsElement = document.getElementsByClassName("months")[0]
var monthList = ["Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
for (var month in monthList) {
    var newMonth = document.createElement("span")
    monthsElement.appendChild(newMonth)
    newMonth.setAttribute("class","month-hover")
    newMonth.innerHTML = monthList[month]
   

}
```

```css
.month-hover:hover{
  color:#27e779 !important;
}
.month-hover{
  padding:0 7px;
}

.months {
  color: #AAAAAA;
  position: relative;
  left: 350px;
  top: 90px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="calendar-base">
        <div class="months">
            <span class="month-hover">Jan</span>
            <span class="month-hover">Feb</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

If I copy the resulting HTML into notepad it looks like this, looks like whitespace:

```
<div class="months">
            <span class="month-hover">Jan</span>
            <span class="month-hover">Feb</span>

        <span class="month-hover">Mar</span><span class="month-hover">Apr</span><span class="month-hover">May</span><span class="month-hover">Jun</span><span class="month-hover">Jul</span><span class="month-hover">Aug</span><span class="month-hover">Sept</span><span class="month-hover">Oct</span><span class="month-hover">Nov</span><span class="month-hover">Dec</span></div>
```

Comment: Could suggest something to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This could also be done by making changes in JS

```
newMonth.innerHTML = monthList[month].concat(" ");
```